# I have two lines, and I am trying to delete the second line

Tags: uipath

[image]

I have tried this:

`Left(InStr(newLine),(InStr(newLine)-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Split the string at the new line character(s), then take the first part:

```
s.Split(new String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

S.Split(Environment.NewLine).First();